# Is it possible to continue deep linking after first install?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, url-scheme

This is the case which I research:

If a person who didn't installed yet my application, when he/she tap a link which contains a user's profile page on the app, it will direct to App Store. After he/she install the application, can app continue the deep link?

Thank you all.

Comment: Have a look at branch.io

Answer (score -1):

What you referring to is called **deferred deep linking**.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, either using an external tool like [branch.io](http://branch.io) or implementing it yourself, which might be tougher.